# Error 401 (Unauthorized) When making REST calls using Axios with JWT headers included

Tags: jwt, axios, cross-domain

I'm developing a small react node application with JWT passport for authentication. I've tested all the endpoint through postman(by passing token with authorization header) and they are working properly.

This is the call im making from the front-end

```
export const getUsersDetails=()=>{
  console.log( localStorage.getItem('jwtToken'));
  return (dispatch) => {
    return axios.get('http://localhost:3030/users',
             { headers: { 'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('jwtToken') } }
            ).then((data)=>{
                 console.log('data comming',data);
                dispatch(getUsersData(data));
            }).catch((error)=>{
              console.log('error comming',error);
                dispatch(errorgetUsersData(error));
            });
        };
}
```

I have enable CORS by using the the CORS module. this is the how the network calls looks like from the browser
[image]

the authorization header looks like
**`authorization:[object Object], eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.....`**

Should this be like **`authorization: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.....`**
Is this the reason why im facing this issue? How to overcome this?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve a similar issue on a MERN stack, by configuring axios globally in the react application, by adding **Bearer** and one space, in front of the token that is assigned globally.

`axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] =`Bearer ${token}`;`

initially, it was without Bearer and i kept getting a 401 status code.

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want authorization in your app, it depends on how you have done your back end. If everything is ok trough postman, show how your headers in postman look when you have tasted. I use xsrf token and here is how my request header look:

```
    {headers: 
           {"Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "*",
            "X-XSRF-TOKEN": this.$cookie.get('XSRF-TOKEN')}
    }
```

Maybe you should just put `"Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "*"`